# how can we do reverse iteration of last four items in the XmlNodeList

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, loops, c#-4.0

At this point It is displaying items in reverse order with no limit. XmlNodeList can have many items. I would like to display only last four items. How can I find or display last four items in the list? Anyone?

```
XmlNodeList MyTestList = MyRssDocument.SelectNodes("test/holder/item");

string Title = "";
string Link = "";


for (int i = MyTestList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    XmlNode MyTestDetail;

    MyTestDetail = MyTestList.Item(i).SelectSingleNode("title");
    if (MyTestDetail != null)
        Title = MyTestDetail.InnerText;
    else
        Title = "";

    MyTestDetail = MyTestList.Item(i).SelectSingleNode("link");
    if (MyTestDetail != null)
        Link = MyTestDetail.InnerText;
    else
        Link = "";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just replace the following line:

```
for (int i = MyTestList.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

By this:

```
for (int i = MyTestList.Count - 1; i >= (MyTestList.Count - 4) ; i--)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = MyTestList.Count; i >= 4; i--)
{
    XmlNode MyTestDetail;

    MyTestDetail = MyTestList.Item(i).SelectSingleNode("title");
    if (MyTestDetail != null)
        Title = MyTestDetail.InnerText;
    else
        Title = "";

    MyTestDetail = MyTestList.Item(i).SelectSingleNode("link");
    if (MyTestDetail != null)
        Link = MyTestDetail.InnerText;
    else
        Link = "";
}
```